# V8: Why does WeakReferenceCallback not get called?

Tags: javascript, v8

When I try to make a Persistent handle weak, why does the WeakReferenceCallback not get called?  See the following sample:

```
void myWeakReferenceCallback(v8::Persistent<v8::Value> theValue, void *theParameter)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "myWeakReferenceCallback");
}

void testWeakReferenceCallback()
{
    v8::Persistent<v8::Value> persistent_value;
    {
        v8::Persistent<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New();
        v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope;
        v8::Local<v8::Value> local_value = v8::NumberObject::New(5.0);
        persistent_value = v8::Persistent<v8::Value>::New(local_value);
        persistent_value.MakeWeak(NULL, myWeakReferenceCallback);
        context.Dispose();
    }
    persistent_value.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two problems:

1. You're disposing the weak handle before V8 has a chance to invoke the callback. You need to dispose it *inside* the callback.
2. V8 doesn't invoke weak handle callbacks until it does a GC.

Try this:

```
void myWeakReferenceCallback(v8::Persistent<v8::Value> theValue, void *theParameter)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "myWeakReferenceCallback");
    theValue.Dispose();
}

void testWeakReferenceCallback()
{
    v8::Persistent<v8::Value> persistent_value;
    {
        v8::Persistent<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New();
        v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope;
        v8::Local<v8::Value> local_value = v8::NumberObject::New(5.0);
        persistent_value = v8::Persistent<v8::Value>::New(local_value);
        persistent_value.MakeWeak(NULL, myWeakReferenceCallback);
        context.Dispose();
    }
    //persistent_value.Dispose();
    while (!v8::V8::IdleNotification()); // force GC
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I was under the impression that I needed to call Dispose (i.e. release the strong reference) on the Persistent handle before the callback would be called.  But now it makes sense.  I released the strong reference when I made it it weak, duh!